# $ \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} | \sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k \sqrt{k}| $ Did I do it right? How to do the last step?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

I need to find:

$$ \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} | \sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k \sqrt{k}| $$

So I calculate:

$$ \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} | \sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k \sqrt{k}|  = \lim_{n \to +\infty} |\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k \sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{n}} | $$

Denominator grows to $\infty$, so I can use stolz theorem:

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} |\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k \sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{n}} |  = \lim_{n \to +\infty} |\frac{\sqrt{2n}}{\sqrt{n} - \sqrt{n-1}} | \implies[\frac{\sqrt{2}}{0} ] $$

So I have to transform that a bit:

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} |\frac{\sqrt{2n}(\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n-1})}{n - n + 1} | = \lim_{n \to +\infty} |\sqrt{2}n + \sqrt{2n^2-2n}| \implies \infty - \infty$$

Another transformation:

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} |\frac{2n^2 - 2n^2 + 2n}{\sqrt{2}n - \sqrt{2n^2-2n}}| = \lim_{n \to +\infty} |\frac{2n}{n(\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{2-\frac{2}{n}})}| = \lim_{n \to +\infty} |\frac{2}{\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{2-\frac{2}{n}}}| \implies[\frac{2}{0} ]$$

... and I feel like it doesn't lead nowhere. Can somebody tell what do I do wrong?

Comment: $\dfrac{\sqrt2}{0}=\infty$ and FINISH.

Comment: I don't think that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is in your numerator:

Using Stolz-Cesaro you should get
$$\frac{\sqrt{2n}\color{blue}{-\sqrt{2n-1}}}{\sqrt{n} - \sqrt{n-1}}$$

Now, all goes well and converges to $\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$.

Comment: Are you sure? Those elements of sum will not "eat each other" leaving just the last one in the longer sum?

Comment: Look at the upper limit of the sum. So, you get two more members going from $n-1$ to $n$.

Comment: ohhh, yeah, you are right, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. :-)

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{split}
\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k \sqrt{k} &= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left((-1)^{2k-1} \sqrt{2k-1} + (-1)^{2k} \sqrt{2k}\right)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( \sqrt{2k}-\sqrt{2k-1}\right)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2k}+\sqrt{2k-1}}
\end{split}$$
Thus $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2k}}\leq \sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k \sqrt{k}\leq \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2k-1}}$$
We can use integrals to estimate the bounds
$$\frac 1 {2\sqrt 2}\int_1^{n+1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}\leq \sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k \sqrt{k}\leq \frac 1 2+ \int_2^{n+1}\frac{dx}{2\sqrt{2x-1}}$$
to see that $$\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k \sqrt{k}\sim \sqrt{\frac n {2}}$$
Thus
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} | \sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k \sqrt{k}|=\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}$$

Comment: And without integrals? Can that be done with Stolz lemma only?

Comment: Let me learn about the Stolz lemma :)

Comment: Or Stolz theorem, whatever. You know what I mean.

Comment: *Stolz - Cesaro Theorem

Comment: The limit is actually $\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$.

Comment: Ooops, thanks for catching this.